# Receving message in thread from socket

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a socket program and receiving a message in a thread.  But I am getting a segmentation fault.
When I receive directly without starting a thread there is no such problem (shown in commented part).

In below code I was receiving directly and sending it to the client.Part of code is shown below:

```
if (acceptor->start() == 0)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            stream = acceptor->accept();
            if (stream != NULL)
            {
                /*
                ssize_t len;
                char line[256];
                while ((len = stream->receive(line, sizeof(line))) > 0) {
                    line[len] = 0;
                    printf("received - %s\n", line);
                    stream->send(line, len);
                */    
                pthread_t sniffer_thread;
                if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler,NULL) < 0)
                {
                     perror("could not create thread");
                     return 1;
                }
                //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
                pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
             }
                delete stream;
          }
       }
    exit(0);
```

Now, I am receiving the same in thread function.  It showing segmentation fault.

Code is shown below.

```
void *connection_handler(void *arg)
{
    TCPStream* stream = NULL;
    ssize_t len;
    char line[256];
    while ((len = stream->receive(line, sizeof(line))) > 0)
    {
        line[len] = 0;
        printf("received - %s\n", line);
        stream->send(line, len);
    }
}
```

part of Valgrind output is

```
==5163== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5163== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5163== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5163== Command: ./appdownload 9999 192.5.60
==5163== 
==5163== Thread 2:
==5163== Invalid read of size 4
==5163==    at 0x401975: TCPStream::receive(char*, unsigned long, int) (tcpstream.cpp:30)
==5163==    by 0x40177B: connection_handler(void*) (appdownload.cpp:68)
==5163==    by 0x4E3F181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==5163==    by 0x566947C: clone (clone.S:111)
==5163==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5163== 
==5163== 
==5163== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5163==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==5163==    at 0x401975: TCPStream::receive(char*, unsigned long, int) (tcpstream.cpp:30)
==5163==    by 0x40177B: connection_handler(void*) (appdownload.cpp:68)
==5163==    by 0x4E3F181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==5163==    by 0x566947C: clone (clone.S:111)
==5163==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5163==  overflow in you`enter code here`r program's main thread (unlikely but
==5163==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5163==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5163==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Comment: What does debugger say? What instruction **specifically** is giving the segmentation fault?

Comment: shown valgrind output.

Comment: While the issue with NULL stream is solved, I wonder if you need to delete the stream pointer. I also suggest using C++ thread constructs instead of pthread.

Answer (score 4):

```
TCPStream* stream = NULL; // HERE
ssize_t len;
char line[256];
while ((len = stream->receive(line, sizeof(line))) > 0) // HERE
```

You call `receive` on `NULL` pointer. Valgrind tells you that:

```
==5163== Thread 2:
==5163== Invalid read of size 4
==5163==    at 0x401975: TCPStream::receive(char*, unsigned long, int) (tcpstream.cpp:30) // HERE
==5163==    by 0x40177B: connection_handler(void*) (appdownload.cpp:68)
==5163==    by 0x4E3F181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==5163==    by 0x566947C: clone (clone.S:111)
==5163==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
              //  ^- HERE
```

If you need to pass `TCPStream*` from main thread to new thread function, you can use 4th argument of `pthread_create`:

> The pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling
>   process.  The new thread starts execution by invoking start_routine();
>   arg is passed as the sole argument of start_routine().
>   (Source: `man pthread_create`)

Main thread:

```
TCPStream *stream = acceptor->accept();
(...)
pthread_create( &sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, stream)
                                                      //   ^^^^^^
```

Worker thread:

```
void *connection_handler(void *arg)
{
    TCPStream* stream = (TCPStream *)arg;
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. Then how I need to declare TCPStream *stream object .Globally?

Comment: @user2357643 Either globally or (preferably) pass it as fourth argument to `pthread_create`.

Comment: I passed it as fourth argument.Now showing as Warning: invalid file descriptor 96707392 in syscall read() in valgrind and not able to receive message.But now no segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

After you've shown your valgrind trace, it's obvious that you're just calling `receive` on a null pointer.

---

Hmm, let's see.

```
char line[256];                                              // 256 bytes space
while ((len = stream->receive(line, sizeof(line))) > 0)      // receive up to 256 bytes
{
    line[len] = 0;                                           // put 257th byte in
```

I guess you could use one more byte for that `0` - try to receive up to `sizeof(line)-1`.

Or just use `std::vector` and then `push_back` that 0.

Comment: @user2357643: that's because the "direct" code had a non-NULL pointer to a `stream` object (returned by `accept()`), whereas the `connection_handler` code has initialised it's same-named variable `stream` to `NULL`.  Those two variables have no automatic connection, and the `->receive()` call uses whichever is visible in the scope it's executing in.